# Express JS with Webpack giving cannot find module error

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

Hi I am new with frontend technologies so I have a question around webpack and express js. I am building an application using react , webpack , node and express js. The app.js looks like the following

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    var path = require('path');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
    app.get('/', (req, res) => { // new
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });
    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000'));
```

package.json looks like following

```
     "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 0",
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "start": "nohup webpack-dev-server --mode development --open &",
        "prepublishOnly": "cp -r configuration/* build/"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "ssh://git.amazon.com/pkg/SPSWebApplication"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@stencil-react/core": "*",
        "@stencil-react/theme-default": "*",
        "webpack": "^4.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
        "react": "^16.8.4",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
      },
      "description": ""
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }

        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "html-loader",
                    options: { minimize: true }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
resolve: { // this allows to import 'Foo.jsx'
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json']
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
    })
]
};
```

when i build the code in the build folder it creates dist/app.js,main.js,index.html whenever i try to run app.js it says

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
```

I want to run my application in production environment through dist/app.js but when I do "node app.js" it gives me this dependency issue I am assuming webpack should pull the express dependency in dist/* folder in a minified form which i am assuming it is not doing. Can you please if I am missing anything and my understanding is correct or not?